# Is $\sqrt{10} - \sqrt 6 -\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 3$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following number:

$$
\sqrt{10} - \sqrt 6 -\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 3
$$

How can I prove that this number is irrational?